# Suitable design pattern for retrieving arbitrary data from main window

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In my C# software, I have a number of drawing tools. Each tool has its own class with a common interface. E.g. "Draw rectangle".

Now, many of these tools need to read data from my main window in order to perform their tasks. However, I don't want these tools to be coupled with my `MainForm` class. Obviously, there is a need for a better design. Which design pattern is suitable for the task?

**Q:** How can class X read arbitrary information from class Y, without coupling the two classes?

Comment: **A**: Use *interfaces*.

Comment: As @AndreCalil says, no design pattern is necessary, just create an interface with the methods to retrieve the data and make the MainForm implement this interface.

Comment: Thanks. That's the most straightforward solution. I was thinking of Visitor pattern, but perhaps that would be an overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to abstract `Y` into an interface designed specifically just to allow retrieving the kind of information `X` needs.

At the same time, you don't want to leak into the interface the specifics of a particular implementation you may have in mind (for example your main window).

Comment: Indeed. OP may wish to check out this design pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBridge.aspx

Comment: That's exactly what I'm afraid of. If I make an interface it will be quite hard to keep it clean from the typical 'MainForm' stuff.

Comment: It may be painful, but it's the only way to keep the classes decoupled. You may want to expand the interface hierarchy so that you break the context into several smaller interfaces. Also instead of returning specific classes from `Y`, it's better, again, to return just interfaces. Following this way, you will be able to separate the interfaces from the implementations at all levels, eventually.

Comment: Several smaller interfaces. I'll go for that. Thanks.